# Handling Flutter Webview Back-Button

Tags: flutter, webview

how to make the action button in the appbar go to previous page in flutter WebView
and if there is no previous page then it should navigate back to the application.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Web view'),
        actions:[
          IconButton( //this button 
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
          ),
        ),
        ] 
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: WebViewController()
          ..enableZoom(false)
          ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
            onNavigationRequest: (request) {
              if (request.url ==
                  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Mediterranean_University") {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text("emu uni")));
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
          ))
          ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
          ..loadRequest(
            Uri.parse('https://google.com/'),
          ),
      ),
    
    );
  }
```

i tried this code but it didnt work

```
  Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
      print("onwill goback");
      controller.goBack();
      return true;
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
      );
      return false;
    }
  }
```